# Persistence context not updating when flush() throws exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a somewhat strange situation which I need to deal with, but can't seem to find a solution.
I need to solve a potential race condition on a customer insertion. We receive the customers through a topic, so they come with an id(we keep it because it's the same id we have in a different database for a different microservice). So, if by some chance, after the same customer is committed to the database before the flush operation is actioned, we should update the record in the database with the one that arrived through the topic, if the last activity field on that one is after the last activity field on the db entry.

The problem we encounter is that, while the flush option is recognizes the newly committed consumer and throws the ConstraintViolationException, when it gets to the find line it returns the customer we try to persist above, **not the customer in the database**

The code breaks down like this.

```
try{
                entityManager.persist(customer);
               //at this point, I insert a new customer in the database with the same id as the one I've persisted
                entityManager.flush();
            }catch(PersistenceException e){
                if(e.getCause() instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {

                    dbCustomer = Optional.of(entityManager.find(Customer.class,
                                                           customer.getId()));
                    //update DB Customer with data from persisted customer if the last update date on the persisted customer is after the one on the db customer
                }
            }
```

I tried different options of transaction propagation, with no success, however, and to use the detach(customer) method before trying to find the db customer, however, in this case, the find function returns Null

Thanks

Comment: update comments with your actual code

Answer (score 0):

As soon as a flush fails, the persistence context is essentially broken. If you need to do something with the result of this code block that needs flushing, you need to do that in a new transaction in case of a constraint violation.